# Calling an external Javascript function in html using flask, showing function not defined

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I am using flask to {% extends "base.html" %} and insert {% block js_file %}, then I call functions defined in .js file but receive **uncaught referenceerror is not defined.**
I have a **base.html** containing all the basic elements in all pages. It looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            {% block title %}{% endblock %}
        </title>
        <!--css file code-->
        {% block cssfile %}{% endblock %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='header.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body> 
        ...
         {% block content %}{% endblock %}
         ...
         {% block js_files %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
    ....
```

then in a specific page called **mark.html**, I extend and insert elements first and want to test a function in a separate functions.js file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block cssfile %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='mark.css') }}">
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}
    Mark
{% endblock %}

{% block js_files %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='functions.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    ....
    <script>warn();</script>
    ....
{% endblock content %}
```

**functions.js** has just a testing function:

```
function warn(){
    alert('fired');
};
```

In the end, in Chrome Dev Tools, the entended page looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Mark
        </title>
        <!--css file code-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='mark.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='header.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body> 
        ...
         <script>warn();</script>
         ...
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script src="/static/functions.js"></script>
    </body>
    ....
```

The structure looks fine to me but it's uncaught referenceerror is not defined. I am new to web div so this question may be dumb but I appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you try to import Jquery before the HTML body? ie just after importing your style sheets?

Comment: I figured, it's to do with loading ordering. Because I use` {% extends "base.html" %}` and insert `{% block js_file %}` so the ordering is confusing. I dealt with this by having proper links in `base.html` because that's where everything extends from, so it will for sure load first.

Answer (score 0):

I figured, it's to do with loading ordering. Because I use`{% extends "base.html" %}` and insert {% block js_file %} so the ordering is confusing. I dealt with this by having proper links in base.html because that's where everything extends from, so it will for sure load first.